# Packing C++ application with MySql database

Tags: c++, mysql

I've a c++ application with connects to mysql database, creates table and adds some data into it using the mysql connector library.

The question is following : 
I would like pack my application so for using the the installation of mysql were not required.
Is it possible to do at all ? If yet any hints, references are welcomed.

The application is managed c++ based.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976014/static-linking-of-mysql-in-c-c

Comment: it is regarding linking mysql lib to application, which is not relevant to my question.

Comment: The lib is what contains the program.

Comment: If you meant the embedded server part from library, then thanks +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [MySQL provides an embedded, in-process version](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/libmysqld.html) that doesn't require you to install a separate MySQL server and yet provides [pretty much the same functionality](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/libmysqld-restrictions.html).

Note however that this is subject to license restrictions: you can either use it under a GPL license (and thus you must publish your application's source code if you ever redistribute it to a third-party) or under a commercial license (which you have to pay for, if you want to redistribute your application but not license it under GPL).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a way. Have a look at one of my SO questions - [How can I explore mysql database files (*.frm, *.myd and *.myi) without MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629869/how-can-i-explore-mysql-database-files-frm-myd-and-myi-without-mysql) I am also the one who answered it.

It gives you a hint on how you can carry the MySQL DB engine with you, provided you have successfully dealt with the licensing.